# Console that shifts down from top

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, console

How to make a shortcut that console is shifting down from top of the screen? I am using arch linux with xfce4.
I want something like on this video:
https://youtu.be/J3KiwoOxfkg?t=5m4s

Comment: Matthew is simply handling the scrollbar in the video, its not the terminal window scrolling the other way around.

Comment: That's the first thing I thought, too, but then I wondered if Mateusz is asking about the overall terminal's roll-up behavior towards the end of the video.

Comment: yes I mean this roll-down behaiour from top of the screen. That there is one console active all the time and it rolls down when you press some shortcut

Comment: ok, already foun it. It is ***guake*** application. Shoul I close the thread now or delete?

Comment: @Mateusz - post that as an answer and then accept it.  provide details on guake and a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This application is Tilda or Guake - top-down terminal for Gnome

Comment: And Yakuake for KDE. ;)